# Hide div if database contains value - Angular

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, angular, postgresql

I want to check if a postgresql database contains a specific value. If it is true I want to hide a HTML . Is this possible?

Can I hide elements with CSS & JS, or what should I use to hide the div?

Also, How would we add it in the Div like a NgIF statement

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, vs what's best and the Angular way:

I assume you expect to have an AJAX call similar to:

```
 $http.databaseAPI.get().subscribe(s => { this.hasValue == s.IsActive; });
```

Then, you could do a few things:

```
<div *ngIf="hasValue"></div>
```

Removes element from the DOM. Potentially very performance detrimental if overused.

```
<div [hidden]="!hasValue"></div>
```

Hides the element in the DOM.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'hideme': hasValue === false}"></div>
```

Changes the CSS based on an expression, and would require supporting CSS to hide the element.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. You can get all that information from [angular docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description)

`*ngIf` removes/adds the html elements from the html tree.

```
<div *ngIf="condition">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
```